# Connecting Watson api to client server

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I built a chatbot PoC for client and now I am struggling to connect it to the client server. The chabot resides on premise at the client side but watson assistant is not responding but the ui comes up
Any reason as to why ? How can I make a connection between Ibm watson cloud server and client server

Comment: add more details

Answer (score 0):

I think we caught up on slack already, but if you're not getting a response at all, even an error message, then its likely something to do with the client firewall not letting the calls go out.